# Can 'never' replace 'not'

Tags: negation

> She was **never** the same person Frank met before.

or:

> She was **not** the same person Frank met before.

Is the two sentence exchangeable? Can the “never” replace the “not”?

Comment: Any useful Answer is spoilt by the fact that your examples are artificial.

Both cases would need "… Frank had met before…"

Even then, "She was never the same person Frank had met before…" is 99% unacceptable. Does that much make sense?

"She was not the same person Frank met before…" should be

"She was not the same person Frank had met…" Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do not necessarily mean the same thing.

(Note that "the same person" is used figuratively. Obviously, she *is* the same person—unless it's a different identical twin that's being discussed and the wording is being deliberately misleading. But here, it's talking about behaviour, beliefs, and so on.)

> She was **not** the same person Frank had met before.

This means that her, or her behaviour, has changed between their current meeting and their previous meeting or meetings. *Before* can be taken to mean a single most recent meeting in the past or it can refer to a series of past meetings.

---

> She was **never** the same person Frank had met before.

This is actually ungrammatical—although mostly understandable. However, there are two possible interpretations, and it should be rephrased to match the one that's intended.

> She **had never before been** the person Frank now met.

This means that not only had she not been the the same person in her last meeting with Frank, but she had also not been the same person with him at *any* of their meetings (if there had been more than one).

If there had been more than a single past meeting, **never** is applied to them all as a whole. Without **never** (as in the first example sentence) it may only be talking about a specific meeting in the past—leaving open the possibility that she *could* could have been the same person at some others.

There is another possible interpretation:

> She **would never again be** the same person Frank met before.

This means that something has permanently changed and she won't go back to being who she had been.